# How do you disconnect a USB drive when getting a "this device is currently in use"?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, eject

My daughter had her thumb drive plugged into my desktop, doing some work.  She finished, logged off of her account and I logged into mine.  I noticed that she left her thumb drive in the USB port, and so I tried to safely eject it, but I get the following message:

> Problem Ejecting USB Mass Storage Device
>
> This device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that
>   might be using the device, and then try again.

OK, I give up.  I just logged into my account and the first thing I did was try to eject her thumb drive.  What in heck is currently using it?  I don't have anything else opened/running when I got that message.  How do I determine what program is apparently running and doing whatever it is, against that USB drive?  How do I get whatever it is, to stop so I can safely disconnect the thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/File-management/Unlocker-Portable.shtml) to find out what program has it opened, then close that program. If you cannot exit the program, you can use Unlocker to force the handle closed.

[image: Unlocker showing processes with open handles]

If it is Windows Explorer, you can restart it. En easy way is to hold <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click a blank area in the Start menu:

[image: Restarting Explorer in Windows 7]

Comment: So how do you get the "exit explorer" context menu?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Fixed. (I don’t use that method; the few times I actually had to restart Explorer in Win7, I used an option called “Restart Explorer”. I can’t figure out where it is right now—I’m in XP at the moment—but next time I’m in 7, I’ll see if I can find it and add it as well. And no, it was not a third-party one that used `taskkill`, it was built-in, to my surprise—ie, Microsoft basically acknowledging the need to restart Explorer.)

Comment: +1 for the "Exit Explorer" option. Much easier than opening Task Manger and finding the process.

Comment: After exit of explorer using context menu, how do you get explorer to reload? ctrl+alt+del twice allows you to open task manager to do it, so it seems better to use task manager to exit explorer in the first place.

Comment: It doesn’t reload automatically? It should, that’s part of Explorer (and there’s no point in *building in* an option to kill Explorer without it restarting). Check the task-manager to see if there are other instances. I find that when there is more than one instance of `Explorer.exe` the auto-restart function gets blocked (or at most opens an actual Explorer window instead of just the desktop).

Comment: if everything here fails, might as well **reboot**. it was my case. something with using USB hub and windows not able to handle the motherboard power.

Comment: Anything that works with Windows 8.1? Unlocker portable does not work at all (nothing happens after running it), I also tried IOBit Unlocker (portable), which claims my USB drive is not locked, but Windows disagrees.

Comment: @DavidBalažic, have you tried the installed version? You could also try [Handles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). If no open handles are being reported, then it could be open by a driver instead of by a program. In that case, you need to make sure to run the program (e.g., Process Explorer) as admin to see it.

Comment: I edited this answer to point to the portable version hosted on Softpedia. "Several optional and usually unwanted software programs may be offered during the installation process. This can only be avoided by being careful not to click on the 'next' or 'install' buttons when the text reads e.g.: by clicking 'next' you agree to .... Instead the left button which is usually labelled cancel has to be chosen in order to continue with the regular installation." See http://deletedwikipedia.gawker-labs.com/wiki/Unlocker

Answer (score 11):

The key is to identify the process that has a directory open on the device you need to unmount (I've used the following on Windows 7).

- A search for warning Event ID 225 from Kernel-PnP in Windows Logs / System log file should find a message of the form "(something) stopped the removal or ejection for the device (something)".

This is already explained in the [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1103296/windows-7-error-ejecting-usb-mass-storage-device):

Access "Computer Management" (right-click "Computer" / "Manage")

> System tools -> Event viewer -> Windows Logs -> System

Use 'Find' to search for the event ID.

- You can also install [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to perform a search for the process or application:

Use that utility to search for a handle with the target drive letter (for example f: ), available under Find / Find handle or DLL ... 
That will help identify the offending process / PID, (similar to use of 'lsof' command under Linux), and the process can be stopped manually (e.g. using Task Manager or Process Explorer). You may need to run Process Explorer as Administrator if you are not the owner of the process.

I've found that some apps keep the directory open, even after a file has been saved and closed. Sometimes it is enough to open another file from your C: drive to reset the "current" directory for the app. Also, apps may still be running after the window has been closed. The searches above will help identify which app you need to stop.

Comment: The system log is the only method that pointed out my anti-virus (NOD32) as the culprit, since Process Explorer and other programs can't "spy" on it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that does not require third party tools:

1. Open "Disk Management" (aka "Create and format hard disk partitions")
2. Locate the disk you want to eject from the lower-left stack of Disks.
3. Right-click the disk and choose "**Offline**".
4. You can then attempt again as normal to "Eject Device" from the system tray, which should now succeed.

[image]

One disadvantage to this approach is when you plug in again, you may have to go through the process to put the disk into **Online** mode.

Comment: This is the only way I could eject the drive because Windows Defender was scanning it (observed in Event Viewer). It is a bit of a hassle to remember to put it online next you plug it in. Next time I'll try taking it offline, putting it online, and ejecting before Defender grabs it again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify the process(es) which are using the drive. Run the following command in PowerShell:

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'System' | Where { $_.Id -Eq 225 }
```

It should show an entry with the message like below:

*The application **<executable_path>** with process id **<process_id>** stopped the removal or ejection for the device **<usb_device_id>***.

Try exiting the app or stopping the process otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has its own utility called [Devcon.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

From the site:

> DevCon (Devcon.exe), the Device Console, is a command-line tool that
> displays detailed information about devices on computers running
> Windows. You can use DevCon to enable, disable, install, configure,
> and remove devices.
>
> DevCon runs on Microsoft Windows 2000 and later versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you can trace processes which occupy drive there is no much problem (for example with mentioned earlier Unlocker small tool). However, sometimes this task is not so easy. There is no explicit handle bound with drive (Unlocker or Sysinternals handle or even process explorer won't show anything) but still Windows will not allow to unmount such drive. Advice like logout, restart or kill explorer seems a little exaggerated and hard to accept.

I have these issues mostly on HDD external drives than mere pendrives.

With pendrives you can use eject function from Windows Explorer drives list. When there is no explicit process then it will work.

With external HDDs there is much harder because there is no eject function. And if you check processes you won't find any handles tangled with drive. In reality, even if not shown there is one process which is blocking drive - system with PID number 4. You can trace it with event logger where system will write information that system process under PID 4 did block the operation. You can check if drive wasn't added to SystemRestore monitor (it's one of the reasons).

For other cases I am using simple script and tool USB_Disk_Eject from Quick And Easy Software.

The batch script is:

```
sync
net share %1$ /D
USB_Disk_Eject /REMOVELETTER %1
```

I was experimenting with one additional command

```
fsutil volume dismount %1
```

but it seems I didn't add it to main batch (not sure why).

Sync is a small Sysinternals tool which will force your drives to finalize write operations (from drive cache to drive).

I had only one case where above lines didn't work - it was AVG software and only logout help.

Comment: I was thinking about one process to be traced but ok, maybe Mod idea is more correct.

Answer (score -1):

Restart Windows Explorer

Task Manager(Ctrl+Shift+Esc)

- tab Details > explorer.exe > button End task
- File > New Task > explorer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).